# iOs-Xcode-Do something while video is in playback

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, background-process, audiovideoplayback

i would like to known if it is possible to do something while a video is in playback on the iphone.. it is quite the same of subtitles but i would like to do some action for example vibrate or play an other sound or display a new label...all of this action will be done while the video is playing(And will not affect the videoplayer,that will continue to show the video).Also at a pre-determinated time.. if the video reaches the xx.xx time it will do something while at the yy.yy time it will do a different action...i don't known if it is possible...Can same of you help me with this please? Or if there is a tutorial on the web that explains it..i have done some researches but i have not found a solution...
Thanks i hope you can help me :D

Comment: Yes this is possible, you can use the `AVPlayerLayer` and `AVPlayer` to display the move a `UIView` and place other views or labels above the video player layer.

Comment: Can you please explain better how to do it? I am not so good to use Xcode..Thaks :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode, just start reading about playing movies on iOS.

Comment: okok i'll read it..thaks for your support :D

Comment: hi, i am having some problems to show the current time of a video that is playing...i use the MPMoviePlayerViewController and its property currentPlaybackTime but when i try to show it int the log as an NSLog it just shows 0.000 and even if the video is going on it doesn't increase its self and doesn't print other seconds..Please can you help me?